# How to find on which post a specific image uploaded to stack.imgur.com is embedded?

Tags: support, search, images

Is it possible to find where an image uploaded to stack.imgur.com has been used, if one doesn't know the the title of the question, nor the name of the author of the question?

I am interested to know how to find the site and the title of the question in which an image was posted and linked, if possible.

Comment: [Google it, maybe](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisGzA-lOKGvDidz7NjGtujXMO6mNHiS8k1p01irtrt6Y9QRxN8qw8ui0E4epBe6sVvp4gOlE61sKgAG5XCDsqtIeHA7CcPqkSkBuLqYRqS_1PYPyMcnnTHYksltgb-yXVlFeSjW2UKs-7QPkQ5SNVjYjl6sL9AaKyYZr8Zm6RMRRoUAt887fPEocUwnHch8yxSkwx1i7H3KbR-3c-l9ZCmC9_1mFd_1X02sj6D6HcarWEY0k1d5ea1dmt2WyOrqTdgmj0-PXC9IwJG2O-iHNIJuwLaaWUnRWlXlG1FJ2JexObQoXyi0LBZy6we6VqYXt_1vnV4c3IlK_11CM1hTUSNW-XMSHWOmQgA) ... ?

Comment: searching for `url:https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlgkW.png` didn't reveal anything, nor on the [networkwide search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=i.stack.imgur.com%2FDlgkW.png) so if that image has been in a post, it is now deleted. Maybe a mod is willing to do an search with `isdeleted:1` but results from that, if any, will only be nice to know as you can't answer a deleted question.

Comment: This image is presently accessible at : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlgkW.png . The first time I saw it was probably on Stack Overflow. But what I am interested for is more general. If one have the name of an image which is on  i.stack.imgur how to proceed to go to the question from which the image is issued.

Comment: In order to make clear my question, another example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qcFH.gif . I know from where this image comes because I posted the question to which the image is linked. The image is not deleted. The question is not deleted. So, that is not my present question. Now, suppose that someone had only the above link, can he go to the forum and to the question ?

Comment: hmm, url search is hopelessly broken. I found the post of your first sample but only because I went through Google first. :/  something is borked in Elastic

Comment: Because I now know the site (and that is small enough in number of posts) this SEDE query works: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1097054

Comment: That's strange ! When I click on https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlgkW.png . I immediately get to the image.

Comment: Why is that strange?

Comment: @rene I believe SEDE is the answer. And hopefully also [SE API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&url=*7qcFH.gif*&filter=default&site=math&run=true)

Comment: @AndrewT. SEDE is really bad at free-text search because it most often can't visit all Posts.body within 2 minutes. see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279702/add-full-text-search-and-semantic-search-to-data-explorer and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312697/158100

Comment: @AndrewT. why does that SE API call work and the on-site search does not?

Comment: @rene. What is strange is that you succeed to find the query/1097054 from which my own image is issued, while one cannot find from where the image DlgkW.png is issued.

Comment: @JJacquelin yeah, Stack Overflow has too many posts to go over. If a query doen't return a result in 2 minutes it gives up.

Comment: OK. I understand. Thank you very much to all of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this url search functionality needs to be fed with an url in double quotes.

Normally you use the `url:` search directive to find specific urls in a post. You would use it like so:

> [`url:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlgkW.png"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FDlgkW.png%22&mixed=0)

Leaving out the `"` at the start and end  of the URL you're looking for will result in no hits.

This also works on the [network-wide search](https://stackexchange.com/search), using one of your examples from the comments:

> [`url:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qcFH.gif"`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2F7qcFH.gif%22)

If you know a bit of the rough time range of the date and the type of post (question or answer) you can use [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1097080) as an alternative:

```sql
select top 1 id as [Post Link]
from posts
where body like '%https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlgkW.png%'
and posttypeid = 1 -- Q (answer will be 2 )
and creationdate between '2019-01-01' and '2019-08-26'
```

but you might give that a few tries with shorter date ranges if you run out of resources (which is the confusing error message you get if your query run any longer than 2 minutes)

When run today it will find you

[How to distinguish between a linear region and a quadratic region](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57599214/578411)

for that particular image.

Comment: That is the question that I was looking for. Bravo, well-done. I learned a lot on the search about images.

Comment: Enclosing the URL with `""` (double quotes) works though... [url:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlgkW.png"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FDlgkW.png%22&mixed=0)

Comment: @AndrewT. then that was my "bug"

Answer (score 2):

Using [Stack Exchange's API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) is probably one of the more reliable ways to find the post in which the image is linked, *provided you also know **the site***.

Select the site, then input the `filename.ext` enclosed with `*` (for wildcard) in the `url` text field and <kbd>Run</kbd> the query. Then click either the `question_id` (if the image is on the question), or `answer_id` (if the image is on the answer).

Example:

- Stack Overflow and `https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlgkW.png`:

  - [Direct API link](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&url=*DlgkW.png*&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)
  - [Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57599214)
- Mathematics and `i.stack.imgur.com/7qcFH.gif`:

  - [Direct API link](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&url=*7qcFH.gif*&filter=default&site=math&run=true)
  - [Answer Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3317563)

---

This can only search for *Q&A post* on Stack Exchange. This approach is ineffective for images used in SE chat, or anywhere outside of SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

That second [image url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlgkW.png) you mentioned does return a [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306953/sum-of-exponential-growth-and-decay/3317563) when you just Google it:

> [image]

The first one (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlgkW.png) doesn't return any results other than this question, which leads me to believe the original question / answer was deleted.

Comment: It is kind of funny how Google indexed that. It finds the url in the comment but for that Math post it claims the most unique part (7qcFH.gif) is missing, yet adds the page to the result. Magic.

Comment: Google works in mysterious ways, @rene...